# Recycler view no retrivie photo, name and status, how to solve?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I implemented search via query using firebaserealtime but now it is not displaying name, photo, or status, the standard thumbnail / profile is displayed when doing the search and clicking the searched item is really the source item. I'm just having trouble displaying the name, photo, status data. could someone help me already tried to put inside onstart but it doesn't work. Thank you very much in advance. any help is welcome. before implementation, a photo, name, status was displayed. What am I doing wrong?

In debug
getName or getStatus no return data :(
But if I do a search by the name of the user and when I click the search the search result in the click event is corresponding to the search name yes it works. problem -> but it's just not displaying photo, name, status.

[image]

DB STRUCTURE
[image]

MyActivity Code:

```
   public class FindFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView FindFriendsRecyclerList;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    private SearchView searchView;
    private Query query;

    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friends);


        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        FindFriendsRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_recycler_list);
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.materialSearchPrincipal);


    }





    private void fetch(Query query) {

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts > options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Contacts>() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Contacts parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                return new Contacts(Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString(),

                                        Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("status").getValue()).toString());
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
            {
                holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);


                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }

        };

        adapter.startListening();
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        Query query =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        fetch(query);
        adapter.startListening();

    }








    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .child("Users").orderByChild("name").equalTo(s);

                if(s.equals("")){
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference()
                            .child("Users");
                }

                fetch(query);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

Contacts - Model

```
public class Contacts {

    public String name, status, image;

    public Contacts(String name, String status)
    {

    }

    public Contacts(String name, String status, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @Alex Mamo Hi Thanks for your reply. added db image

Comment: If you try to log `snapshot.child("status").getValue()).toString()` is it something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Yes return users info. name,photo status etc...

Comment: Inside  `onBindViewHolder` method,  what returns `model.getName()`?

Comment: no returns :( androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{218b3542 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f080128 app:id/user_profile_name}